# Connect ceiling fan romex to switch controlled outlet or directly to switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, ceiling-fan, multiway-switch

I’m installing a ceiling fan in the living room. I want to control the ceiling fan light and fan on separate switches—the ceiling fan is capable. However, the wiring in the switch box made me pause. Current 3-switch controls hallway, outlet, and stairwell lighting (stairwell switch is on separate breaker and is a 3-way… trying to avoid unnecessarily messing with it). I want to abandoned the outlet and put a blank over it since it’s in a walkway and isn’t convenient or necessary. Can’t definitively determine if the wiring/outlet should be left alone and ceiling fan connected to it (and forget about using separate switches for light/fan) or if I can remove the outlet, tie the wiring into wingnuts, and put a blank over. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! ***(More info below pics)***

## Outlet wiring pics:

[image: Left side of outlet]

[image: Right side of outlet]

[image: Inside outlet box]

## Switch wiring pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

*Additional info: This install would be in Missouri. No previous ceiling fan or ceiling lights—60’s house. I have all my equipment: mounting bracket & box, 50’-100’ of romex (bought 6 months ago can’t remember length) wing nuts, new outlet box (just in case) & blank outlet plate, new 4-switch box/plate, new switches, and of course the ceiling fan (I could be forgetting an item I’ve already bought). Marked and centered where the install will take place. All breakers identified. Locations of wiring to outlet and switch identified. Wiring to outlet comes directly from basement. Wiring to switch runs up the wall from outlet, into attic, back down to switch. Switch and outlet about 8-9’ (W) apart. All switches will be replaced with new since the outlet switch is stab-back. Switch only controls the 1 outlet and is not tied into or from anything outside the outlet. I am aware there was a similar question asked/answered but could possibly only partially apply to my specific situation. If there is a question/answer involving all the things I’ve listed with my wiring situation, please forward it because I didn’t see it!*

Comment: The switch has a white wire. That implies either 3-way switch (one wire hot or switched hot, two wires travelers) or a "special" switch that needs power for itself and therefore needs neutral (timer, smart switch, motion detector, etc.) - so please clarify the type of switch as that could be an issue. You almost *never* want to abandon a receptacle unless it *has* to be covered for some reason. I am 95% certain you can make that receptacle an always hot, feed to the switch box, install double switch and feed from there to light/fan.

Comment: **Key question: How many wires (besides ground) in the Romex you plan to use?**

Comment: 2nd the comment to not remove the outlet. Current code requires one every 6' on a wall. While you're not required to update to meet current code (unless you're changing wiring, _ahem_), there's nothing wrong with exceeding code requirements. _You_ may not use this outlet, but someone in the future (maybe future you) might need it. And nobody, but _nobody_ ever said "Dang, there are too many outlets in this house!".

Comment: Sorry I was trying to comment on this again the other day but the add comment button wasn’t appearing for whatever reason and I forgot. 

To answer your question @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact the switch is being fed directly from the outlet, as far as I know, and doesn’t power anything else. And the switch is  basic, just turns the outlet on and off—nothing fancy or modern.  and I bought regular 14-3 and outdoor/damp rated 14-3 (it was on sale for literally 20 min online at Lowes  for 100 ft for $15 so I definitely took advantage of it!). So there’s 4 wires within the romex.

Comment: @FreeMan I’m not necessarily worried about others using this outlet in the future. My plans are to reinforce the load, replace the beam in the attic, & remove the 5’ wall the outlet’s on. There’s an outlet in the hallway, another on the wall closer to the hallway in the kitchen (6 total in kitchen), 3 in the living room, 3 in dining. So plenty to spare. Lol what I’m not trying to do is make more work for myself by finding complicated work-around’s (if unnecessary) to keep this outlet. But I’m going to keep it always hot & just leave it be-so that’s all I needed to know.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact what I think I’m going to do is investigate the switch wiring a bit further. I’ve been up in the attic to see how the wiring travels from one place to the other and the only romex I found that fed into that switch panel was from the outlet. The wiring for the other two switches are traveling from downstairs-up. The guy who owned this house before me also seemed to think dedicating an entire breaker to the doorbell transformer was a good use of electricity so perhaps I’ve missed or overlooked something.

Comment: Dedicating an entire circuit to a doorbell transformer is *not* a waste of electricity. It is (sort of) a waste of a breaker, but the extra $5 - $10 for an "extra" breaker is no big deal. However, it is a waste of a breaker *space*, which are often in short supply.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact yeah there are no breakers left, so it definitely was a waste of breaker space. I’m not too worried about it at this moment though.